# How to achieve a Heart-rate-monitor styled plot in Coreplot

Tags: core-plot

I'm using the Real Time Plot (in CorePlotGallery) to graph incoming ECG heart data. This works, but since it autoscrolls the X axis horizontally as new data arrives (which I don't want) I've modified the "-newData:" method in RealTimePlot.m with:

```
if (self.currentIndex >= kMaxDataPoints) self.currentIndex = 0;
```

This allows the plot to "chase" itself over & over on the graph. Great.

Problem: When the plot wraps back to the start, Coreplot connects the plot end point with the new start point, resulting in a horizontal plot line cutting through the entire graph, from the last point back to the first.

Q1: Is there a way I can get Coreplot to not connect these two data points?

Q2: Alternatively, is there another way of achieving a "heart rate monitor" styled plot in Coreplot with a real time data stream?

Answer (score 0):

Add a dummy data point between the two where you want the break and give it a value of `NAN` or `nil`. You'll end up with one more data index than points you want displayed.

Alternatively, use two scatter plots to display the data. Add data points to one and remove them from the other and then switch when you get to the end.

Comment: Clever idea to add a NaN ([NSDecimalNumber notANumber]) to the plot data! But Coreplot skips over the NaN data point and still connects the last and first plotted points with a horizontal line. Very frustrating...

Comment: Just to follow up: Once a NaN is inserted into the plotData, Core Plot won't look beyond it to data added thereafter. Until removed, the NaN acts like a "hard stop" for the data. Q: How does one plot real-time data with discontinuities?

Comment: Please show the code you're using. I just tested both `nil` and `NAN` values in the *Plot Gallery* example app and it performed as I described above.